# Boundaries and contours in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image with non closed curves of 1-pixel width on it. I want to grab this curves as a list of points (in proper order). I found `bwboundaries` function which tries to wrap all non-zero pixels and thus in this case returns duplicate points:

```
>> A = [0 0 0; 1 1 1; 0 0 0];
>> b = bwboundaries(A)

ans = 

    [5x2 double]

>> b{1}

ans =

     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     2     2
     2     1
```

`bwtraceboundary` do the same

```
>> bwtraceboundary(A, [2 1], 'E')

ans =

     2     1
     2     2
     2     3
     2     2
     2     1
```

Is there any standard method to get matrix like [2 1; 2 2; 2 3] immediately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It produces double entries because your region is only one pixel wide. I don't think there's a standard method that handles your special problem directly. However, you can simply use the [unique()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html) function to eliminate double entries of the result.

To keep the original order of the points, just do:

```
b = bwboundaries(A);
[dummy, ind] = unique(b{1}, 'rows', 'first');
contour = b{1}(sort(ind), :);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However `unique` sorts points and breaks the contour. I guess it's simplier to refine `boundaries` output using something like `ind = find(all((points(3: sz, :) == points(1: sz - 2, :))')) + 2;
points = points(1: ind - 1, :);`

Comment: You can restore the original order after `unique` did its job. I updated my answer accordingly.